# Doing VLOOKUP on "Nth" value using LARGE function in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am working on an Excel file which compiles client data to group them by region/city, using a COUNTIFS function, as:

```
60  Ottawa    
10  Otterburn Park    
14  Outremont    
40  Philipsburg    
59  Pierrefonds    
59  Pincourt
...
```

I would then like to use a combined VLOOKUP + LARGE function to determine the 10 or 15 cities where most of our clients are. Naturally I tried something along the lines of:

1st value

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(Lists!$R:$R),Lists!$R:$S,1,FALSE)
```

2nd value

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(Lists!$R:$R),Lists!$R:$S,2,FALSE)
```

etc.

However in this example, the first entry with a 59 count (Pierrefonds) keeps appearing and I am unable to have entry "Pincourt" displayed using this method. What am I doing wrong. Should I go about this a different way?

Thank you!

Comment: You could sort the data by city and then get the number using offset()...

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula, pay attention to the `$O$1:O1` reference. This needs to be placed in at least the second row, with the `$O$1:O1` reference pointed at the cell above.

Put in first cell make sure the references are correct and copy/drag down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(S:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($R$1:INDEX(R:R,MATCH(1E+99,R:R)))/(($R$1:INDEX(R:R,MATCH(1E+99,R:R))=AGGREGATE(14,6,$R$1:INDEX(R:R,MATCH(1E+99,R:R)),ROW(1:1)))*(COUNTIF($O$1:O1,$S$1:INDEX(S:S,MATCH(1E+99,R:R)))=0)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked absolutely brilliantly, thank you so very much!!